# Slack Newline Character not working in URL Request

Tags: java, url, slack-api

I am writing a simple url request in Java to use the Slack postMessage API call like this:

`URL slackAPIURL = new URL("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=" + apiToken + "&channel=" + channel + "&text=" + message + "&as_user=true&pretty=1");`

However, when I want to use the newline character (\n) in the string `message`, the literal \n appears instead of a newline. All of the other markdown commands work such as ** for bold or __ for italics. How can I get \n to work using this URL?

Comment: Have you tried url-encoding the newline characters? That is, instead of replacing newlines with `\n`, encoding them as `%0A` ?

Comment: The literal string `\n` is the JSON newline character; I suspect using `\n` for a newline will only work if you're passing the argument as JSON in a POST body.

Comment: The %0A worked perfectly. Thanks!